# Is it possible to "invert" an SVG file? Not the colours, but the actual areas/paths?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have an SVG file, and I want to create the opposite of it.  It's a monochrome icon, and I want a version where the logo is transparent and the rest of the rectangle is filled paths.

In theory it feels like it should be a common problem, and something like Inkscape should have an "Invert Paths" (or similar) function, but in practice I couldn't find any relevant help in Inkscape or Google?

Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. Make sure your design is entirely composed of paths. There can't be any groups or text objects, etc. Ok to have multiple path objects though.
2. Draw a rectangle around the whole thing
3. Select your design as well as the rectangle
4. Choose "Path" > "Exclusion"