# Make this square a circle

Tags: svg

This I have extracted from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84312/96678). Following is the SVG markup that has been posted there.

What I wanna know is, how do I make this square a circle? Basically once done, it should be a background with no fill, circle with the star shape taken out of it.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" enable-background="new 0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
     <path d="M4,5v391h391V5H4z M291.703,327.4L199.5,260.414l-92.204,66.991l35.219-108.403L50.312,152h113.97L199.5,43.608L234.719,152h113.97l-92.204,67.003L291.703,327.4z"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Star Image]

Comment: Using an SVG editor? Just editing the text? Using additional elements or not? Using clip paths or not? There are too many answers to this question as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  

xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  

width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" enable-background="new 0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">  

<path d="M199.5,5C91.528,5,4,92.528,4,200.5S91.528,396,199.5,396S395,308.472,395,200.5S307.472,5,199.5,5z M291.703,327.4

L199.5,260.414l-92.204,66.991l35.219-108.403L50.312,152h113.97L199.5,43.608L234.719,152h113.971l-92.205,67.003L291.703,327.4z"
/>
</svg>
```

To satisfy curiosity: I just opened your SVG in illustrator, modified the square to make it a circle and retrieved the path part of the resulting SVG code.

Now, if you need code to be dynamically generated, that would be another story and you should give more details about your workflow (i.e. use of javascript)

Comment: You're welcome! Now if the downvoter may explain why he did so, it might help me to give more suitable answers or to fit requirements.

Comment: Yeah! The entire Stack Exchange system needs some enforcing mechanism to explain the downvote, if and whenever there is a downvote!

Comment: @Vinny - if it's worth aynthing to you, I've upvoted.

Comment: @BillyKerr Nope, I don't really care about reputation, I was just curious about understanding the reason of the downvote... I still don't have it... Thanks anyway ^^

Comment: It was likely because you provide absolutely no explanation at all, which makes your answer not very helpful

Comment: At least, there should be some courtesy to mention that in a comment. Just a vote down, without in or out is not so helpful either...